# Understanding Java Encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am trying to determine if an in-house method will decode a byte array correctly given different encodings.  The following code is how I approached generating data to encode.

```
public class Encoding {

  static byte[] VALUES = {(byte) 0x00, ..... (byte) 0xFF};
  static String[] ENCODING = {"Windows-1252","ISO-8859-1"};

  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    for(String encode : ENCODING) {
      for(byte value : VALUES) {
        byte[] inputByte = new byte[]{value};
        String input = new String(inputByte, encode);
        String houseInput = houseMethod(input.getBytes());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is when it comes making the call to the house method, what encoding will it send to that method?  It is my understanding when Java stores a String, it converts it to UTF-16.  So when I am sending Input.getBytes(), is it sending the UTF-16 encoding byte or the encoding scheme that I set when I created a new String?  I am guessing that it is UTF-16, but I am not sure.  Should the house method be???

```
houseMethod(input.getBytes(encode))
```

Comment: Bytes have no encoding; characters and strings have one

Comment: @fantaghirocco wrong. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html defaultBytes vs utf8Bytes

Comment: @fantaghirocco No, characters and strings in Java don't have an encoding. The encoding is what you need to **convert** between characters/strings and bytes.

Comment: @Laurentiu ok I got it, thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See String.getBytes():

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

You are well advised to use the String.getBytes(Charset) method instead and explicitly specify the desired encoding.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) `String.getBytes()`:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's
>   default charset, storing the result into a new byte array

So the bytes that the in house method gets depend on which OS you are, as well as your locale settings.

OTH, `String.getBytes(encoding)` ensures you get the bytes in the encoding you pass as parameter.